# Data Transfer from SQL Server To Mysql for selected objects on a daily basis?

Tags: mysql, sql, etl, database-migration, data-transfer

I need to take data from microsoft sql server DB (selected tables) to mysql database. how to achive this in a daily basis by using any open source ETL or Any other ways

Comment: I voted to close this as off-topic but I guess it is also too broad. Maybe it would be better to post this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

For DB migration, you can use tools like : `SQL SERVER data tools`. Check it out here:

[Database migration using SqlServer data tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdR6WV4kh2Y)

ETL is a much wider concept and you do a lot more stuff in it rather than just copying data from a table to another.

I've personally worked on `Talend` which is a open-source ETL tool.You can find tons of videos on youtube and elsewhere. In my opinion, you should understand what `ETL` is first and what it is capable of.

Here's a one to get you started:

[Talend for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdR6WV4kh2Y)

Let me know if this helps.